# unexpected behaviour of using declaration with private inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider this small example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct C:private A
{
    using A::foo;
};

struct D:private B, public C
{
};

int main()
{

    D myD;
    myD.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this example with g++ 4.8.1, I get these errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:32:9: error: request for member ‘foo’ is ambiguous
     myD.foo();
         ^
prog.cpp:5:10: note: candidates are: void A::foo()
     void foo()
          ^
prog.cpp:5:10: note:                 void A::foo()
prog.cpp:13:10: note:                 void B::foo()
     void foo()
```

I would have thought that the lookup for D::foo() would have ignored B::foo() because B is privately inherited from D and there's no `using` declaration in D. I would have thought that the only visible foo() would be A::foo().

But clearly I thought wrong and I've misunderstood an aspect of the `using` declaration.

Can anyone explain:

- Why B::foo() is visible here
- How to make the complier see only A::foo() without changing the public interfaces of A, B or C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** Accessibility is **ignored** during name lookup : it doesn't matter if the member is public, private or protected : all are equally considered, which is why `A::foo` and `B::foo` are ambiguous within `D`.

C++ standard section 3.4 [basic.lookup]:

> The access rules (Clause 11) are considered only once name lookup and function overload resolution (if applicable) have succeeded

**2)** Simply bring it into scope within `D` :

```
struct D: private B, public C
{
    using C::foo;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

> Why `B::foo()` is visible here

Access restrictions don't affect the visibility of names during name lookup; they are only checked after lookup has found an unambiguous match.

> How to make the complier see only A::foo() without changing the public interfaces of A, B or C?

Add `using C::foo;` to `D`. That hides any declarations of the same name in base classes, so only that overload is visible within `D`.

Alternatively, qualify the function call: `myD.C::foo()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why the conflict arises. Thankfully though, it's pretty easy to resolve:

```
struct D:private B, public C
{
    using C::foo;
};
```